# Calling a NavigationController (to push another view controller) from a CollectionViewCell

Tags: swift

Here is what I'm trying to do.

```
class UserProfileHeader: UICollectionViewCell {

    lazy var button: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        //...
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleButtonTapped), for: touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()

    func handleButtonTapped() {
        print("action working now")
        // How to push another vc here?
    }

    // ...
}
```

I want to call a navigationController to push(show) another ViewController here in the collectionViewCell. How can I access there? I tried, not worked. Is it because of MVC pattern? Cell can't talk with others? Or is there any ways to make it? like using Delegate/Protocol? I don't know much about those things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create one custom delegate and set to its viewcontroller and then when you tap on collectionview cell button called that delegate method and it will invoke inside your viewcontroller there you can push the view controller

```
func handleButtonTapped() {
 //Your delegate method showuld be invoked here
 delegate?.buttontappFromCollectionViewCell()

 }

//Now inside your view controller 
 func buttontappFromCollectionViewCell() {
let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "storyboardName", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yourViewControllerIdentifier")
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: May be I was asking to directly open storybaord from UICollectionViewCell. But the best way is always open inside the ViewController if possible

Comment: I agree. It'd be even easier to hook up an action in the storyboard.

Comment: thank you. Is there a way that I can do that without storyboard?

Comment: Yes, you create and can load xib file using NSBundle if you do not want to use storyboard.